# In Dart, an async scope of async function makes me confused

Tags: dart, asynchronous, scope

There was a time when I made a code with this structure while making a code.

```
void main() async {
  print('one');
  first();
  print('five');
}

void first() async {
  print('two');
  await second();
  print('four');
}

Future<void> second() async {
  print('three');
}
```

Above code's result was

one
two
three
five
four

And I was very confused by this result.
I thought the await syntax would wait for the second function and output "four" right away.

However, "five" was printed at fourth and "four" was printed at the right after.

Is there anyone who can tell me why "five" is printed at fourth sequence?

---

Edit 1.

My initial question was ambiguous, so I add a new explanation.

When I executed below code, the output sequence is

one two three four five.

```
void main() async {
  print('one');
  first();
  print('five');
}

void first() async {
  print('two');
  second();
  print('four');
}

Future<void> second() async {
  print('three');
}
```

Yeah that output is so reasonable for me, because `print('two')`, `await second()` `print('four')` is in same function's - `first()` - scope.

But, in the case of `await second()`, why `print('fout')` is not executed right after `await second()`??

Why `await` statement break the function scope??

This is my real curiosity...

Comment: You are not awaiting the `first()` call and `first()` should return `Future<void>` since it is marked `async`.

Comment: Oh, my question was very ambiguous, so I am going to add a new explanation. Please wait for a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think where you get confused is that when we call `async` functions, we run them synchronously until first `await`:

> Note: Although an async function might perform time-consuming operations, it doesn’t wait for those operations. Instead, the async function executes only until it encounters its first await expression (details). Then it returns a Future object, resuming execution only after the await expression completes.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#handling-futures

If we go thought the first posted example, it is executed in the following order:

1. Print "one".
2. Calls `first()` and continues the execution inside here.
3. Print "two".
4. Calls `second()` and continues the execution inside here. The `await` statement is first coming into play when we return from `second()` which will give us a `Future<void>` to `await` on.
5. Print "three".
6. `second()` returns a `Future<void>` which is generated automatically from the fact that the method is marked `async`. In this example, the `Future` are already completed with a value but the later `await` are still going to move further executing of `second()` into a new event on an event queue.
7. We `await` the `Future<void>` from `second()`. Since this is the first `await` in `first()` we will now return a `Future<void>` from `first()`. Yes, this happens even if the method is marked to return `void` so by using `void` you are really just making it "impossible" for the caller to `await` the `Future`.
8. We are not back at `main()` and continues to run the rest of this method. Which means we print "five".
9. Since we don't have more code to execute, we check the microtask event queue (and afterwards if nothing is found event-queue) for any events to be executed. These events is added when a e.g. `Future` gets completed with a value which happen immediately when `second()` was done.
10. The first (and only) event to execute are one that continues the execution of `first()` from the point of `await second();`. We now print "four".

Comment: Oh, if so, I will really appreciate to you...

Comment: @Jun What example do you want me to go though?

Comment: To the point, the links says it all clear. 

Comment: @julemand101 I'd like to see a complete structure of how the execution of my initail question's code...

Comment: @Jun Updated answer with a detailed explanation about what is going on in the first example you have posted. I hope it answers your questions. If not, just ask. :)

Comment: @julemand101 I have one question! In 7 step, after first ```await``` in ```first()``` return Future<void>, the codes behind the first ```await``` (although it contains another await statement) go to event queue?? And the codes in event queue will be executed after call stack is empty?

Comment: @Jun Well, the code is getting subscribed to the `Future` so when the `Future` are completed with a value, we can add an event on the event queue to continue the execution of the rest of the method.

Comment: And yes, we will check the event queue every time we cannot execute more code following normal code execution flow. I recommend reading: https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks to your explanation, I now understand the clear answer to my question. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247537/discussion-between-jun-and-julemand101).

Answer (score 2):

When you don't await the Future returned from an async function, then any non-async code within that function will be executed immediately and synchronously.

So, when you remove all awaits, the effect is that you don't have any code executing asynchronously - it's the same result as if none of the functions were marked `async`.

The behavior you saw in the first example was because you did not use `await` in `main`, but you *did* use await in `first`. This changes the order of execution, such that the code after `await` in `first` will be deferred until after all the synchronously executable code has finished executing.

It might be more clear if, instead of separating these into separate methods, we expand the methods such that all of the code is contained within `main`, and also replace the usage of await with `.then()`.

For your first example:

```
void main() async {
  print('one'); // Executes immediately
  print('two'); // Executes immediately
  (() async { 
      print('three'); // Executes immediately
  })().then((_) {
    print('four'); // Execution deferred
  });
  print('five'); // Executes immediately
}
```

Whereas your second example expands straightforwardly:

```
void main() async {
  print('one');
  // Begin first()
  print('two');
  // Begin second()
  print('three');
  // End second()
  print('four');
  // End first()
  print('five');
}
```

Comment: At a side of call stack structure, ```print('one')``` is pushed and poped remaining 'one' in console. And ```first()``` is pushed. To pop ```first()``` call from stack, ```first()```, call's ```print('two')``` is pushed and poped. In ```await second()``` line,  ```print('three')``` is pushed and poped directly because of ```await``` statement. But the ```await second()``` call announce to call stack "hey! with await, this ```first()``` call is end! Go ahead the next code written by after me! But I have remained call ```print('four')```. So I will send it to callback queue!" Is it right...?

Comment: Yep, that's the general idea! @julemand101 has added an even more detailed run through to their answer as well